# Material UI Dialog - Force Box to fill DialogContent Space

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `Dialog` component with a max width and a minimum height. Within the `DialogContent` I want to stretch a Box to fill out the remaining space of `DialogContent`. Ultimately I want a background image to fill this Box.

I have been unable to find a way to stretch the Box to fill the remaining space of the dialog content.

```
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        maxWidth="md"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        PaperProps={{
          sx: {
            minHeight: "60%"
          }
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Test dialog</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent
          sx={{
            bgcolor: "#41f1b6"
          }}
        >
          <DialogContentText>
            You can set my maximum width and whether to adapt or not.
          </DialogContentText>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              width: "75%",
              height: "100%",
              bgcolor: "#ff7782"
            }}
          >
            I want this to fill the rest of DialogContent
          </Box>
        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
```

Here is what I see:

[image: Rendered dialog]

I want the red background color to stretch all the way down to the end of the green.
I have played around with a bunch of different height values, but nothing I have tried has worked so far. Surely there is an easy way? Notice I can set the width to `75%` and that works fine.

Here is the corresponding [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-surf-eci36f?file=/demo.js:0-1315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both the container and the content to be flex, after that you can use flex-direction:column and flex-grow:1 to make it take up the rest of the space.

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-feistel-t9y189