# How to Add a Scrollbar To a DIV When Height Is Unknown?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

I have a `div` with significant content that needs a scroll bar.  This `div` is inside a "flex" layout that is in turn displayed by an Angular `MatDialog` component.  In other words, there is no fixed height and no way (that I've found) to specify such in a dynamic way.

Every answer I come across about this says that specifying a `height` is the right thing to do.  That does work but it also breaks the layout since no fixed height is correct and `height: 100%` only works if *every* parent element also has it (which is difficult at best if not completely impractical/impossible).

*How do I get a scrollbar on such an element and keep the dynamic sizing?*

It's okay if the scrollbar is always there; it doesn't have to be automatic.

Comment: can you put out a sample? I answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/75515375/4475288 I am curious when you say that all parent heights need to be 100% to work, the dialog is already absolute positioned. I don't think you need that but your use case might be different. regardless I think a combination of flex column grow and 100% height in the dialog should work just like in the example I pasted.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll` will always show a scrollbar, but as you can't/don't want to add a size constraint, the element will never be able to overflow as it will continue to grow dynamically with its content, hence rendering the scrollbar useless. Eventually you will need a container that is too small for its content to fit in to be able to scroll it. Maybe a `max-height` relative to the viewport will work for you.

Comment: (1) Filling up the flex space (similar question) isn't an issue.  It's all about the scrollbar.
(2) overflow-y: scroll does add the scrollbar but, as you say, it's always inactive.  A large max-height didn't work; if the flex region grows to big (to fit content because it won't scroll) then eventually a scrollbar appears around the entire dialog and that's just ugly.  A small max-height is wasteful or breaks layout.

Comment: There is no avoiding adding some size constraint as the container *must* overflow to trigger a working scrollbar. One can't do without the other. But maybe I am reading you wrong, so please add a (vanilla) running [reprex] for my understanding. For the dialog (maybe even `body`) you need to have `overflow: hidden`. Too many *ifs* and *buts*. Post code...